# Can you use a CASE statement with OrderBy in an LINQ to Entities query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm wonder if someone can transform the SQL below to a LINQ to Entities query

```
SELECT Name, IsEmployee, IsQualityNetwork
FROM Person
ORDER BY CASE WHEN IsQualityNetwork = 1 or IsEmployee = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, Name
```

I tried using Linq Dynamic but when this code is executed:

```
var p = ctx.People
    .OrderBy("CASE WHEN IsQualityNetwork = 1 or IsEmployee = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END")
    .OrderBy(e => e.Name);
```

I get the exception:
{"No property or field 'CASE' exists in type 'Person'"}

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
var p = ctx.People.OrderBy(p => (p.IsQualityNetwork == 1 || p.IsEmployee == 1) ? 0 : 1)
                  .ThenBy(p => p.Name);
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a translation of your SQL to LINQ.

```
var query = from p in ctx.People
            let order = p.IsQualityNetwork || p.IsEmployee ? 0 : 1
            orderby order, p.Name
            select new
            {
                p.Name,
                p.IsEmployee,
                p.IsQualityNetwork,
            }
```

I've used the fluent query syntax so I could show you the `let` keyword.  `let` allows you to declare a range variable that can then be reused in your query, this can be very useful if you've got a conditional that gets used in a lot of places, or if you need to chain multiple conditionals.