# How Order by Case in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by, case

I have this answer [Entity framework OrderBy "CASE WHEN"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152220/entity-framework-orderby-case-when) but this only handle two options

```
var p = ctx.People.OrderBy(p => (p.IsQualityNetwork == 1 || p.IsEmployee == 1) ? 0 : 1)
                  .ThenBy(p => p.Name);
```

I have a text field and want rows appear on an specific order. In sql I would do:

```
ORDER BY CASE when name = "ca" then 1
              when name = "po" then 2
              when name = "pe" then 3 
              when name = "ps" then 4
              when name = "st" then 5
              when name = "mu" then 6
         END
```

Comment: You just add more condition operators `OrderBy(p => p.Name == "ca" ? 1 : p.Name == "po" ? 2 : .....)`

Comment: @juharr ohh I see. Wont  be pretty but would do the job. Thanks.

Comment: juharr's solution should work. Try to sort the results in C# side instead of in DB *if possible*(be careful if the ordered result is used in the DB query), that makes the code clearer.

Comment: @DannyChen What you mean sort in C# ? OrderBy do the order on DB isnt?

Comment: I mean you can try to load the data into the memory and sort it using LINQ to Objects, to avoid generating so many "SWITCH WHEN" statements for your query.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about creating a map of your sort order?

```
var sortOrder = new Dictionary<string,int>
{
  { "ca", 1 },
  { "po", 2 },
  { "pe", 3 },
  { "ps", 4 },
  { "st", 5 },
  { "mu", 6 }
};

var defaultOrder = sortOrder.Max(x => x.Value) + 1;

var sortedPeople = ctx
  .People
  .AsEnumerable()
  .OrderBy(p => (p.IsQualityNetwork == 1 || p.IsEmployee == 1) ? 0 : 1)
  .ThenBy(p => sortOrder.TryGetValue(p.Name, out var order) ? order : defaultOrder);
```

Comment: @DannyChen really? I don't have a sample app to check it against. Why do you think it wouldn't work?

Comment: Because you are testing with linq to objects. the `sortOrder[p.Name]` should fail when parsing to sql query.

Comment: @DannyChen I understand I was testing with linq to objects, I was wondering why it would fail when parsing to SQL was all.

Comment: `sortOrder[p.Name]` calls the indexer, I don't think it can be parsed to sql statement. We know it gets the value by key of the dictionary, but the query provider doesn't, and it shouldn't know.

Comment: @DannyChen ok, I see what you mean. I also found in the docs that LINQ to SQL doesn't support complex types for sorting. I'll see how I can update the answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @DannyChen I updated the answer. I'm not too happy with it, though, since you can't make use of IEnumerable, but if the OP knows that the data will be small, I guess it's not too bad.

Comment: @GaurangDave I have Sublime Text magic to thank for the speed :)

Comment: First if you want to transition from `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable` just use `AsEnumerable` instead of `ToList` to avoid an extra unneeded list.  Second you really should do both the `OrderBy` operations after that so you can do a `OrderBy().ThenBy()` so it will maintain both orderings.  As it is the first DB side ordering could be undone by the code side ordering.

Comment: @juharr thanks for that. I didn't realize you can convert it to linq to objects with `AsEnumerable()` and retain deferred execution. And thanks for catching the `ThenBy()` - I should have spotted that. I updated the answer to reflect these points.

Comment: Also if a default case is needed you could change that to `p => sortOrder.TryGetValue(p.Name, out var order) ? order : defaultOrder`

Comment: @juharr yeah, I like that better to avoid any exceptions. Thanks again