# c# Facing problem to order my Quarters by LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have unordered list of quarters stored in `List<string>` and i want to sort that data by LINQ. After Sorting order should look like below list of quarters.

> 2010 FY 2011 FY 2012 FY
>
> 1Q 2013 2Q 2013 1H 2013 3Q 2013 4Q 2013 2H 2013 2013 FY
>
> 1Q 2014 2Q 2014 1H 2014 3Q 2014 4Q 2014 2H 2014 2014 FY

i got one bit similar post from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50225386/13722367

which i try to follow but now facing compilation error.

This way i tried

```
    var sortOrder = new Dictionary<string,int>
    {
      { "1Q", 1 },
      { "2Q", 2 },
      { "1H", 3 },
      { "2Q", 4 },
      { "3Q", 5 },
      { "2H", 6 },
      { "4Q", 7 },
      { "FY", 8 }

    };

    var defaultOrder = sortOrder.Max(x => x.Value) + 1;

    List<string> _lstQtr = new List<string>();
    _lstQtr.Add("2H 2013");
    _lstQtr.Add("1Q 2013");
    _lstQtr.Add("2Q 2013");
    _lstQtr.Add("2013 FY");
    _lstQtr.Add("1H 2013");
    _lstQtr.Add("3Q 2013");
    _lstQtr.Add("4Q 2013");

    _lstQtr.Add("2H 2014");
    _lstQtr.Add("2Q 2014");
    _lstQtr.Add("2014 FY");
    _lstQtr.Add("1H 2014");
    _lstQtr.Add("3Q 2014");
    _lstQtr.Add("4Q 2014");
    _lstQtr.Add("1Q 2014");

    _lstQtr.Add("2012 FY");
    _lstQtr.Add("2010 FY");
    _lstQtr.Add("2011 FY");

    _lstQtr = _lstQtr.OrderBy(s => (s.Contains("FY") ? s.Substring(0, 4) : s.Substring(s.Length - 4)))
        .ThenBy(p => (sortOrder.TryGetValue(p, out var order) ? order : defaultOrder))
        .ToList();
```

What is wrong in this line for which getting error

```
.ThenBy(p => (sortOrder.TryGetValue(p, out var order) ? order : defaultOrder))
```

Please suggest me a good approach to order my quarters as a i mention how quarters should appear at top.

Comment: Where is this data coming from? Perhaps a better approach would be to parse the data on a arrival and use your own type to store it - then you can easily write code to sort by year and then by quarter/half/full

Comment: BTW, what's the error you're getting?

Comment: _throwing compilation time error_ - what is the error?

Comment: my code is very small. just run the code and then you can understand why compilation time error is there.

Comment: @TridipBhattacharjee, you code doesn't have **compilation** errors

Comment: `.Substring(0, 4)`, what specifically was this supposed to extract?

Comment: year from 2014 FY.

Comment: anyways thanks issue solved and i posted the working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for posting answer and comments. This way i solved it. Thanks

```
    var sortOrder = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "1Q", "1" },
        { "2Q", "2" },
        { "1H", "3" },
        { "3Q", "4" },
        { "4Q", "5" },
        { "2H", "6" },
        { "FY", "7" }
    };

    //var defaultOrder = sortOrder.Max(x => x.Value) + 1;

    List<string> _lstQtr = new List<string>();
    _lstQtr.Add("2H 2013");
    _lstQtr.Add("1Q 2013");
    _lstQtr.Add("2Q 2013");
    _lstQtr.Add("2013 FY");
    _lstQtr.Add("1H 2013");
    _lstQtr.Add("3Q 2013");
    _lstQtr.Add("4Q 2013");

    _lstQtr.Add("2H 2014");
    _lstQtr.Add("2Q 2014");
    _lstQtr.Add("2014 FY");
    _lstQtr.Add("1H 2014");
    _lstQtr.Add("3Q 2014");
    _lstQtr.Add("4Q 2014");
    _lstQtr.Add("1Q 2014");

    _lstQtr.Add("2012 FY");
    _lstQtr.Add("2010 FY");
    _lstQtr.Add("2011 FY");

    _lstQtr = _lstQtr.OrderBy(s => (s.Contains("FY") ? s.Substring(0, 4) : s.Substring(s.Length - 4)))
        .ThenBy(s => (s.Contains("FY") ? sortOrder[s.Substring(s.Length - 2)] : sortOrder[s.Substring(0, 2)]))
        .ToList();
```

Another Way. little changed in code

```
List<string> _lstQtr = new List<string>();
_lstQtr.Add("2H 2013");
_lstQtr.Add("1Q 2013");
_lstQtr.Add("2Q 2013");
_lstQtr.Add("2013 FY");
_lstQtr.Add("1H 2013");
_lstQtr.Add("3Q 2013");
_lstQtr.Add("4Q 2013");

_lstQtr.Add("2H 2014");
_lstQtr.Add("2Q 2014");
_lstQtr.Add("2014 FY");
_lstQtr.Add("1H 2014");
_lstQtr.Add("3Q 2014");
_lstQtr.Add("4Q 2014");
_lstQtr.Add("1Q 2014");

_lstQtr.Add("2012 FY");
_lstQtr.Add("2010 FY");
_lstQtr.Add("2011 FY");

_lstQtr = _lstQtr.OrderBy(s => (s.Contains("FY") ? s.Substring(0, 4) : s.Substring(s.Length - 4)))
    .ThenBy(s => GetSortIndex(s.ToString()))
    .ToList();


private static int GetSortIndex(string qtr)
{
    int index = 0;
    if(qtr.Contains("1Q"))
    {
        index = 1;
    }
    else if (qtr.Contains("2Q"))
    {
        index = 2;
    }
    else if (qtr.Contains("1H"))
    {
        index = 3;
    }
    else if (qtr.Contains("3Q"))
    {
        index = 4;
    }
    else if (qtr.Contains("4Q"))
    {
        index = 5;
    }
    else if (qtr.Contains("2H"))
    {
        index = 6;
    }
    else if (qtr.Contains("FY"))
    {
        index = 7;
    }
    return index;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this solves the problem:

```
    var sortOrder = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "1Q", "1" },
        { "2Q", "2" },
        { "1H", "3" },
        { "3Q", "4" },
        { "4Q", "5" },
        { "2H", "6" }
    };

    List<string> _lstQtr = new List<string>();
    _lstQtr.Add("2H 2013");
    _lstQtr.Add("1Q 2013");
    _lstQtr.Add("2Q 2013");
    _lstQtr.Add("2013 FY");
    _lstQtr.Add("1H 2013");
    _lstQtr.Add("3Q 2013");
    _lstQtr.Add("4Q 2013");

    _lstQtr.Add("2H 2014");
    _lstQtr.Add("2Q 2014");
    _lstQtr.Add("2014 FY");
    _lstQtr.Add("1H 2014");
    _lstQtr.Add("3Q 2014");
    _lstQtr.Add("4Q 2014");
    _lstQtr.Add("1Q 2014");

    _lstQtr.Add("2012 FY");
    _lstQtr.Add("2010 FY");
    _lstQtr.Add("2011 FY");

    _lstQtr = _lstQtr.OrderBy
        (
            s => (s.Contains("FY") ? s.Substring(0, 4) + "z" : 
                    s.Substring(s.Length - 4) + "." + sortOrder[s.Substring(0, 2)]))
        .ToList();


    var transformed = _lstQtr.Select
        (
            s => s + ": " + (s.Contains("FY") ? s.Substring(0, 4) + "z" :
                    s.Substring(s.Length - 4) + "." + sortOrder[s.Substring(0, 2)]))
        .ToList();
```

But it is not pretty. It converts the string to a new string that then is used for sorting. Look in transformed to se what the new values are. But as other has suggested, it might be better to create a new kind of object from the string.

Comment: _I think this solves the problem_ - What is the problem?

Comment: @PEK not giving right order, See few quarter has only FY that is why there coming before as per year wise ordering and rest of  quarters which has 1Q,2Q then should sort first by year and then 1Q, 2Q wise
`2010 FY 2011 FY 2012 FY

1Q 2013 2Q 2013 1H 2013 3Q 2013 4Q 2013 2H 2013 2013 FY

1Q 2014 2Q 2014 1H 2014 3Q 2014 4Q 2014 2H 2014 2014 FY `

Comment: @TridipBhattacharjee, I see. I have updated the code and it should work now. But still not a solution I am proud of :-)