# SQL to LINQ - Case Statement

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I am re-writing a SQL statement to LINQ for the first time. I am not too sure how to properly write out my case statement. The runtime does not like how I have written it (I used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225333/how-order-by-case-in-linq) as an example)

My goal is to get my data organized by the case statement. Please let me know what I can modify to accomplish my goal.

My error says:

```
    InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Table>
    .Where(c => c.ID ==(Nullable<int>)10)
    .OrderBy(c => c.column1)
    .ThenBy(c => _sortOrder_0.TryGetValue(
    key: c.column3,
    value:_order_1)?_order_1:_defaultOrder_2)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()
```

Original SQL query:

```
    SELECT column1, column2, column3 from table where ID = # order by column1, 
    Case column3 When 'X' Then 1 When 'Y' Then 2 When 'Z' Then 3 End
```

LINQ:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var sortOrder = new Dictionary<string, int>
        {
            {"X", 1 },
            {"Y", 2 },
            {"Z", 3 },
        };
    var defaultOrder = sortOrder.Max(x => x.Value) + 1;
    int order;
    var dataTest = _context.TableModel
        .Where(x =>
        (x.ID == 10)
        )
        .Select(x => new TableModel
        {
            column1 = x.column1,
            column2 = x.column2,
            column3 = x.column3,
        })
        .OrderBy(x => x.column1)
        .ThenBy(x => sortOrder.TryGetValue(x.column3, out order) ? order : defaultOrder)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Side note: I am using ID = 10 for testing purposes. Thank you for your time!

Comment: EF can't translated `sortOrder.TryGetValue ..` to sql, have you tried query like this `.ThenBy(x => x.column3 =='X' ? 1 : (x.column3 =='Y' ? 2 : (x.column3 =='Y' ? 3 : defaultOrder)))` or use `.ToList()` after `.Select` to order in client side.

Comment: For what it's worth, Entity Framework can execute your original SQL query *directly.*  No need for translation to EF Linq.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Comment: @RobertHarvey yep, I know. I tried to use the FromSqlRaw method, and it also hated that. It was throwing an error that one of my columns did not exist

Comment: One option is to just pull down the data from the DB then do the ordering in memory.

Comment: If your query works in SSMS, it will work as a raw query.

Comment: @RobertHarvey no, please see the [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#limitations) section, particularly the `The SQL query must return data for all properties of the entity type.` one.

Comment: @GuruStron: A condition that is easily fulfilled.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it does not make statement that if query works in SSMS, it will work as a raw query, truthful. Moreover there can be performance implications which can make this condition not so easy to handle.

Comment: Not sure the point you're making here, @guru, but I think you're being overly pedantic about it.  I've used raw queries for years, and have never had problems with them.  I verify all my queries in SSMS before I put them into EF, which has proven to be an effective technique for writing reliable queries for EF.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I mean that if table has a lot of columns and/or columns with a lot of data selecting all of them when you need only 3 may be not good or easy.

Comment: You don't have to do that.  All you need is a small DTO with only the 3 fields that you require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ternary operator for all cases in your `ThenBy` clause:

```
 .ThenBy(x => x.column3 == "X" 
      ? 1 
      : x.column3 == "Y" 
          ? 2 
          : x.column3 == "Z" 
                ? 3 
                : defaultOrder)
```

Answer (score 0):

It'll be kind of yucky, but...

```
context.TableModel.Where(x => x.ID == 10)
    .OrderBy(x => x.column1)
    .ThenBy(x=> x.column3 == "X" ? 1
        : x.column3 == "Y" ? 2
        : x.column3 == "Z" ? 3
        : defaultOrder)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync();
```

Basically just a giant nested if statement.
Also, the select statement is redundant if your table only has three columns.

My suggestion is to make an enum out of all your column3 values and then orderby that instead. It'll be more efficient because enum assigns int values to each item.

Comment: Why select statement is redundant? Possibly OP wants to select only some fields from the table, not all of them (i would recommend to create DTO in such case, but without  `TableModel` there is not enough info to state that select is not needed).

Comment: Making `column3` an enum wouldn't work because the ordering is done on the DB where it's a string and not a numeric value.  Unless you mean they should store the integer values in the DB instead.

Comment: @guruStron you are correct, and I will amend my statement.

Comment: @juharr when the type of the property is an enum, entity framework will convert the value to integers. During runtime, the enum can be accessed for the string value.

Comment: Depending on the version of EF it can convert the value in the DB to an enum in memory, but it's still a string in the DB where the ordering is done.  Also the example does not seem to be exhaustive so you'd still need a default and specify which ones to not default.

Comment: OP stated EF Core, so unless value conversions are used, the value in the DB will be an int. Creating a default is done by making the first or last enum property "Default". The Orderby enum can be accomplished by .OrderBy(x => (int) (x.column3))