# How does ternary operator with hard coded return values work in LINQ's OrderBy?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I came across this answer [Entity framework OrderBy “CASE WHEN”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17152315/6197785)
 ,
I always use `OrderBy` to order by a specific property, but didn't know how something like this could be useful or even exist:

```
foos.OrderBy(f => f.Val3? 1 : 0);
```

I created `Foo` class to observe how it's working:

```
class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Val1 { get; set; }
    public string Val2 { get; set; }
    public bool Val3 { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format($"{Id}> {Val1}, {Val2}, { Val3}");
    }
}
```

In `Main`:

```
List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>
        {
            new Foo{Id=1,Val1=5, Val2= "a", Val3= true},
            new Foo{Id=2,Val1=4, Val2= "c", Val3= false},
            new Foo{Id=3,Val1=1, Val2= "f", Val3= false},
            new Foo{Id=4,Val1=2, Val2= "d", Val3= true},
            new Foo{Id=5,Val1=9, Val2= "i", Val3= true},
            new Foo{Id=6,Val1=7, Val2= "h", Val3= true},
            new Foo{Id=7,Val1=6, Val2= "g", Val3= true},
            new Foo{Id=8,Val1=8, Val2= "b", Val3= true},
            new Foo{Id=9,Val1=3, Val2= "e", Val3= false}
        };

var orderedFoos = foos.OrderBy(f => f.Val2 == "c" ? 1 : 2).ToList();
```

In `orderedFoos` the first and second items are swapped (the "c" item becomes first):

[image]

and when:

```
var orderedFoos = foos.OrderBy(f => f.Val2 == "c" ? 3 : 1).ToList();
```

the "c" item becomes last.

I used multiple values with different properties, but couldn't notice a pattern

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do that, it's not ordering by that property, but by the value returned by the conditional operator. So, each record gets a "sort value" and the list gets sorted by that:

```
new Foo { Id=2, Val2= "c", VirtualSortValue = 1}, // because "c"
new Foo { Id=1, Val2= "a", VirtualSortValue = 2}, // because not "c"
new Foo { Id=3, Val2= "f", VirtualSortValue = 2},
new Foo { Id=4, Val2= "d", VirtualSortValue = 2},
new Foo { Id=5, Val2= "i", VirtualSortValue = 2},
new Foo { Id=6, Val2= "h", VirtualSortValue = 2},
new Foo { Id=7, Val2= "g", VirtualSortValue = 2},
new Foo { Id=8, Val2= "b", VirtualSortValue = 2},
new Foo { Id=9, Val2= "e", VirtualSortValue = 2}
```

How the remainder is sorted depends on the underlying storage (when talking about Linq-to-Entities). For usage on a `List<T>` you use `Enumerable.OrderBy()`, whose sort is [guaranteed to be "stable"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This method performs a stable sort; that is, if the keys of two elements are equal, the order of the elements is preserved. In contrast, an unstable sort does not preserve the order of elements that have the same key.

Answer (score 0):

The image shows excactly what is going on.
To get a better understanding, create a list of the orderby lambda statement:

C is true, all others are false, since there is no other way to order them the only logical way to 'sort' them is in the order they came in (so no sorting).

When you print the results, it returns C at top, and then all other items in the order you put them in.