# Advance LINQ Ordering in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, linq

I have an `ObservableCollection<myListType> Items`.
Each item in Items has a Project Name which can be "Administrative" and "Non-Administrative"(can be anything). I want to sort my Items using LINQ so that the items with Non-Administrative Project Name will be put on top of Administrative item.

So far i use,

```
Items.OrderBy(x => x.ProjectName != "Administrative").ThenBy(x => x.ProjectName == "Administrative");
```

But it doesn't sort the way i want and when i debug, I saw

> "The Expression not supported".

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you doing with the `IEnumerable<myListType>` returned by your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you use a CASE statement with OrderBy in an LINQ to Entities query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152220/can-you-use-a-case-statement-with-orderby-in-an-linq-to-entities-query)

Comment: The code you've shown would not have the error "The Expression not supported". I think you need to refine your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you use `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` shows a lock of understanding how `OrderBy` works. Please see the following example

```
| ID | Project Name   |
-----------------------
| 1  | Administrative |
| 2  | X              |
| 3  | Administrative |
| 4  | X              |
```

With the expression `x.ProjectName != "Administrative"`, `OrderBy` will look at all items and sort them by whether `ProjectName` is not `"Administrative"`.

```
| ID | Project Name   | ProjectName != "Administrative" |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Administrative | false                           |
| 2  | X              | true                            |
| 3  | Administrative | false                           |
| 4  | X              | true                            |
```

This will yield the following order

```
| ID | Project Name   | ProjectName != "Administrative" |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Administrative | false                           |
| 3  | Administrative | false                           |
| 2  | X              | true                            |
| 4  | X              | true                            |
```

because `true` is deemed *greater* by `OrderBy`. `ThenBy` now tries to order the groups internally, i.e. all items that matched a single *"order key"* are tried to be ordered by another criteria. See the following table for visualization

```
| ID | Project Name   | ProjectName != "Administrative" |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Administrative | false                           | Items for false
| 3  | Administrative | false                           |
=========================================================
| 2  | X              | true                            | Items for true
| 4  | X              | true                            |
```

Since `ProjectName == "Administrative"` has the same value for all items withing a single *group*, no subsequent ordering happens.

#### How can you achieved the desired outcome?

Simply use

```cs
Items.OrderBy(x => x.ProjectName == "Administrative")
```

Since `ProjectName == "Administrative"` is `true` for all administrative projects and `true` is deemed greater by `OrderBy` they show up last.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I want to add something anyway. So after successfully order the list i want, i notice that the type of the list generated by OderBy method becomes "IOrdered..(something):". So anyone who use this OrderBy method, dont forget to change it back to the type you want. In my case ObservableCollection<myListType>.

Thanks

Comment: @Damar admittedly, but this holds true for all `Enumerable` extension methods.

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirements, "Non-Administrative" should be put on top of "Administrative".
You can do this:

```
var list = Items.OrderByDescending(x => x.ProjectName);
```

it will put "Non-Administrative" before "Administrative".

**Edited**

[for non-administrative name that has 'AAA']:

```
var result = Items.OrderBy(p => p.ProjectName  == "Administrative").ThenBy(p => p.ProjectName);
```

Comment: Unless there is a project named `"AAA Project"`, which will be put below `"Administrative"`. Please note that the non-administrative projects may have *any* name.

Comment: If that's the case he can do this: 
var result = Items.OrderBy(p => p.ProjectName  == "Administrative").ThenBy(p => p.ProjectName);

Comment: This is true if they want to order them alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo on dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t5THVW)

You make sure `ProjectName  == "Administrative"` is always on the bottom.

```
var result = Items.OrderBy(p => p.ProjectName  == "Administrative");
```

Comment: The `ThenByDescending` is completely useless. Please see my answer.

Comment: Hi @Damar, Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers